# Why can't I access the property of the object?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm trying to access the property "**providerAccountId**" from the "**accountsCardModel**" object, but for some reason, it's undefined. I'm using Kendo Observable object, and get method usually works. I even tried using the dot notation to access the property stored within the object (no luck).

The following line, the console throws the error *"Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"*

```
provAccId: accountsCardModel.get("providerAccountId")
```

I don't know how Kendo internally works. Perhaps, kendo tries to execute the code before I want it to, but that's unlikely. Perhaps it's an hoisting issue.

```js
var accountsCardModel = kendo.observable({
    providerAccountId: "", 
    datasource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: MobileStorage.getServerURL() + "/cabinet/wicket/bookmarkable/com.web.services.AccountsService",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    op: "read",
                    provAccId: accountsCardModel.get("providerAccountId")
                },
                beforeSend: function(jqXHR){
                    Utils.xhr.queue(jqXHR);
                },
                complete: function(jqXHR) {
                    Utils.xhr.dequeue(jqXHR);
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            parse: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    }),
    showAccountDetails: function(providerAccountId){
        this.set("providerAccountId", providerAccountId);
    }
});
```

Comment: try this ```provAccId: this.get("providerAccountId")```

Comment: Was worried that the scope of "this" keyword would have changed, but I tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution:

Traced the call stack, and it's frustrating to see the Kendo executing my lines behind the scene without my knowledge. Instead of sending read: parameters, I called it as a function and it worked.

**Before:**

```
    datasource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: MobileStorage.getServerURL() + "/cabinet/wicket/bookmarkable/com.web.services.AccountsService",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                op: "read",
                provAccId: accountsCardModel.get("providerAccountId")
            },
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR){
                Utils.xhr.queue(jqXHR);
            },
            complete: function(jqXHR) {
                Utils.xhr.dequeue(jqXHR);
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        parse: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
}),
```

**Afer:**

```
    datasource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function(options) {
            $.ajax({
                url: MobileStorage.getServerURL() + "/cabinet/wicket/bookmarkable/com.web.services.AccountsService",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    op: "read",
                    provAccId: accountsCardModel.providerAccountId
                },
                success: function(result) {
                  options.success(result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                  options.error(result);
                },
                beforeSend: function(jqXHR){
                    Utils.xhr.queue(jqXHR);
                },
                complete: function(jqXHR) {
                    Utils.xhr.dequeue(jqXHR);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    schema: {
        parse: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            //return response.providerAccounts[0]; // Load only online account, omit autologin
        }
    }
})
```

And it worked!